# How can i see a list of my Twilio account phone numbers by Twilio API?

Tags: twilio

I have a twilio account for sending SMS. However, i need guidance on how to see a list of my account phone numbers by calling its API. I have tried to navigate through the different menus in API but i dont see any option to get list of my account phone numbers. Thank you in advance for your guidance.

Comment: What language do you use primarily?

Comment: You'll want to use the IncomingPhoneNumber resource to get this information. https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers#instance-get

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you want to list the phone numbers you have in your Twilio account through the API you need the [Incoming Phone Numbers list resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers#list).

You can access this easily with the Twilio rubygem like so:

```
require 'twilio-ruby'

@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID, YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN
numbers = @client.account.incoming_phone_numbers.list
numbers.each do |number|
  # do something with the number
  puts number.phone_number
end
```

Comment: hey @philnash. Is there a way I can specify the number of records the `.list` endpoint will return? Right now it always gives 50. I would like to fetch _all_ of my accounts phone numbers, and this is just a subset

Comment: answer to my previous question: the ruby API is actually mis-documented. The proper syntax is: `[...].incoming_phone_numbers.list(page_size:1000)`

Comment: Hell yeah you can! Just use the `PageSize` attribute. You can get a maximum of 1000 items per page. Check out this page for a bit more detail: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/response

Comment: @philnash Hey, How can I acheive this in PHP SDK? I can see on docs that only create method available.

Comment: @CodeCooker Here's a link to the PHP sample for listing phone numbers: https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource?code-sample=code-list-all-incomingphonenumber-resources-for-your-account&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=6.x

Comment: @philnash Wow, Hey thank you so much for super fast reply, and it worked! I'm searching all the way but didn't see this page :)

Comment: @CodeCooker Notifications on Stack Overflow get my attention sometimes  Sorry it was hard to find, but glad it's working for you now!

Comment: @philnash Hey, Hopefully you doing good. I've set to work on a feature called conversation of messsages. that means I will have to show messages that sent by sender/reciver like a chat between two peoples. is there any way Twilio can help on it or i need a complete custom build? I see this https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-create-sms-conversations-php  but not that much helpful

Comment: @CodeCooker not sure what you mean about how Twilio can help? Are you looking for UI components? Or just need a jumping off point for the API requests?

Comment: This needs to be updated to `@client.api.account.incoming_phone_numbers.list` because of the following error: `undefined method `account'`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a PHP version...

```
<?php
namespace App\Test;
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
use Twilio\Rest\API\V2010\AccountContext;
use Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\IncomingPhoneNumberList;
use Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\IncomingPhoneNumberInstance;

class TestClient {
    private $client = null;
    public function __construct() {
        $sid = $_ENV['TWILIO_SID'];
        $token = $_ENV['TWILIO_TOKEN'];
        $this->client = new Client($sid, $token);
    }
    public function getActiveNumbers()
    {
        $context = $this->client->getAccount();
        $activeNumbers = $context->incomingPhoneNumbers;
        $activeNumberArray = $activeNumbers->read();
        $numbers = [];
        foreach($activeNumberArray as $activeNumber) {
            error_log('active number = '.$activeNumber->phoneNumber);
            $numbers[] = (object)[
                'number' => $activeNumber->phoneNumber,
                'name' => $activeNumber->friendlyName,
                'sid' => $activeNumber->sid
            ];
       }
       var_dump($numbers);
       return $numbers;
    }
}
```